# Using a ComboBox selection as directory source for another ComboBox, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, directory

So I have created a form that creates both a `.txt` file and a `directory` with the same name under the directory `C:\Modules`.

I have made it possible to select the `.txt` files from `ModuleSelectorComboBox` and now what I am having trouble getting to work is using the name of the file selected in `ModuleSelectorComboBox` to form part of the name of the directory in `NoteSelectorComboBox`.

```
    public Default()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Modules");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules");
        foreach (string file in files)
            ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }

    private void moduleToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewModule newmodule = new NewModule();

        newmodule.Show();

    }

    private void ModuleSelectorComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear(); //Clears previous Modules Text
        string ModulefileName = (string)ModuleSelectorComboBox.SelectedItem;
        string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Modules\", ModulefileName + ".txt");

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            richTextBox1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
        else
            MessageBox.Show("There's been a problem. Please restart the program. \nError 1", "Error 1", //error 1 is file deleted while the program is running
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Clear();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules");
        foreach (string file in files)
            ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }

    private void NoteSelectorComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ModulefileName = (string)ModuleSelectorComboBox.SelectedItem;
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules\" + ModulefileName); //THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED BUT CANNOT GET TO WORK
        foreach (string file in files)
            NoteSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
}
```

So if 'Module 1' is selected in the `ModuleSelectorComboBox` the directory listing for `NoteSelectorComboBox` will be set to `C:\Modules\Module 1` (ie. `C:\Modules\<NAME OF SELECTED MODULE From ModuleSelectorComboBox>` and so the files in that folder would be shown in the ComboBox.

Comment: You said "//THIS IS WHAT I HAVE TRIED BUT CANNOT GET TO WORK". What is the output of this line? What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get an error, it just simply does not work as a method.

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Not an error. So it compiles but doesn't do what you expected? What is in `ModulefileName`?

Comment: Doesn't do what I expected. ModuleFileName simply links to the selected item in the ModuleComboBox.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. `SelectedItem` is of type `object` and using `selectedItem.ToString()` you should get the text of the combo box.

Comment: I have found a solution to my own question, the answer is below! Thanks!

Comment: I saw that, but I still don't understand why it didn't work in the first place. Don't take it bad but I don't think that using another button to reset your combobox is a good solution. Sure it does the job, but it sounds overlycomplicated for what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

I have created an OnClick(); event that has now solved this issue.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = (string)ModuleSelectorComboBox.SelectedItem;
        NoteSelectorComboBox.Items.Clear();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules\" + (string)ModuleSelectorComboBox.SelectedItem);
        foreach (string file in files)
            NoteSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
    }
```